# ng-class to be only added if <a> exists after given element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items that are grouped by labels, and am using filter to search through this list. The issue is that labels for lists are still showing in the search, however lists themselves are empty, hence I need to hide appropriate label. To do so I can check if anchor tag exists after my label with class `.item`, if it doesn't then I want to add `.hidden` class to the label.

I tried following, but as I am new to angular it obviously didn't work:

```
<div class="label" ng-class="next(a).length <= 0 ? 'hidden'">
  My Label
</div>
```

And this is how whole group/section looks if there are items in the list:

```
<div class="list search-list">
  <div class="label" ng-class="next(a).length <= 0 ? 'hidden'">
     My Label
  </div>
  <a class="item> .. </a>
  <!-- More a tags here -->

  <div class="label" ng-class="next(a).length <= 0 ? 'hidden'">
     My Label 2
  </div>
  <a class="item> .. </a>
  <!-- More a tags here -->
</div>
```

I checked with inspector, relevant a tags are indeed being removed if they don't match search.

UPDATE:

added false case to ng-class, but still no luck

```
  <div class="label" ng-class="next(a).length <= 0 ? 'hidden' : 'shown'">
     My Label
  </div>
```

UPDATE2: Full structure

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
  <ion-content ng-controller="SearchCtrl">

    <div class="list search-bar">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search-strong placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" ng-model="searchFilter">
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="list search-list">

      <!-- Group 1 -->
      <div class="item item-divider" ng-class="angular.next('a').length <= 0 ? 'hidden' : 'shown'">
        My Title
      </div>
      <a
        class="item item-avatar"
        href="#/app/{{item.link}}"
        ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchFilter">
        <img src="img/item.png">
        <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
      </a>

      <!-- Group 2 -->
      <div class="item item-divider" ng-class="angular.next('a').length <= 0 ? 'hidden' : 'shown'">
        My Title 2
      </div>
      <a
        class="item item-avatar"
        href="#/app/{{item2.link}}"
        ng-repeat="item2 in items2 | filter:searchFilter">
        <img src="img/item2.png">
        <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        <p>Description 2</p>
      </a>

    </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: `next(a).length <= 0 ? 'hidden'` is that ternary operator? Doesn't look like.

Comment: @Tushar I believe it is jQlite selector from here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element I'd assume I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: I'm not sure but can you call a function in `ng-class`, perform you condition and return class name? Like `next(a)` can be a function returning class name as a string

Comment: @Ilja I'm not talking about selector, I'm talking about operator `?` used. If it is ternary operator use it as `condition ? truePart : falsePart`. Ex. `cond ? 'hidden' : ''`

Comment: @Tushar ah gotcha, updated my question, now 'shown' is showing at all times

Comment: `.next()` is a property of `element`, it is not `next()` (which could be used independently), note the `.`

Comment: @Claies I tried using it as angular.next(a) .. and element.next(a), I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean, could you explain in bit more detail please?

Comment: `ng-class` is looking for a property on `$scope` that matches the expression you pass in.  in this case, to accomplish what you want, you would have to have a property on `$scope` that represents your specific div.  `next(a).length` would be trying to call a `next()` function on `$scope` which doesn't exist, hence `.length` would always be `undefined`.  you can't use `angular.element` in this context either, since it would have no way to know which element you are trying to evaluate.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a way you can do what you are trying without writing a custom directive, but I'm not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: @Claies if you could provide explanation on how to achieve this using $scope that would help out a lot as well.

Comment: that's what I've been trying to say, I don't think you can accomplish this without creating a custom directive, `$scope` doesn't give you enough information to accomplish what you are trying.

Comment: it might be helpful if you can show the greater picture here, and show the filter that you are using; there is probably information in the filter or the ng-repeat that can be used to manage the logic;  any time you start trying to code based on the DOM instead of your data, you get outside of how angular is structured and generally end up needing to drop to directives.

Comment: basically I think this is an XY problem in hiding.  There are ways you can get the result you need, but you picked one possible solution here, which doesn't really work with the framework.  looking at the problem of how to hide the labels rather than how to find the next element will lead to a better solution.

Comment: @Claies I added full structure to the question, the custom html elements are from ionic framework I am using: http://ionicframework.com/ But I don't thinks this matters to much in this case. The divider divs are what needs to be hidden if related a elements are not present

Comment: looks like two good approaches came from that update.  I would go with the `ng-init` method personally, as it feels more like you are responding to the data instead of responding to what the DOM is doing in response to the data;  the closer to the source, the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to follow the original approach of checking if there is `<a/>` element after your `<div>` you can write a custom directive. Here is one that checks for that condition:

```
.directive('conditionalDisplay', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      if (element.next('a.item').length == 0)
        element.css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
});
```

And here is how I used it:

```
<div class="list search-list">
      <div conditional-display class="label">
        My Label (Not Displayed, because there is no next a element)
      </div>
      <!--<a class="item"> .. </a>-->
      <!-- More a tags here -->

      <div conditional-display class="label">
        My Label 2 (Displayed)
      </div>
      <a class="item"></a>
      <!-- More a tags here -->
</div>
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ytCVxuBnbZAbX0faiQ4m?p=preview

One important thing: Make sure you include jquery for the `next()` selector to work. JQLite does not support `next()` with selectors.

Personally, I like @pgreen2 's approach. It more like angular way of doing stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As described by [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), you could store the results of the filter and then reference like below:

```
<!-- Group 1 -->
<div ng-init="filteredItems = (items | filter:searchFilter)" ng-if="filteredItems">
  <div class="item item-divider">
    My Title
  </div>
  <a class="item item-avatar" href="#/app/{{item.link}}" ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">
    <img src="img/item.png">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <p>Description</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I wrapped the whole group in a div that has `ng-init` which creates a variable called `filteredItems` that us it two other places.  The first is to conditinally render the entire div using `ng-if`.  I believe this will resolve your actual question.  Secondly, I use `filteredItems` in the `ng-repeat` for the anchor tags.

Comment: The code I wrote was untested, there is a chance that having the `ng-if` on the wrapping `div` won't work, so you would need to move it to the the `div`

Comment: I used ng-init="filteredItems = (items | filter:searchFilter)" ng-if="filteredItems" on a div containing label, without a wrapper, and it doesn't work, is this still correct way to use it or do I need to refuter my code to use wrapper div and item in filteredItems instead of item in items? As I want them all displayed initially.